# Not getting a NULL pointer error in C

Tags: c, pointers

I was purposely trying to get a NULL pointer in C but I failed to do this. Here is what I was coding:

```
int main(void) {
  int x; //UNINITIALIZED so that it will represent "nothing"
  int *null_test = &x;
  printf("This should be null   %p \n", null_test);
}
```

But it gave me an address: `0x7fd96c300020` which doesnt seem to be `NULL` as I was hoping.

**Why?** I didn't even initialize`x` but still not null?

Comment: You didn't assign `NULL` to `null_test`.

Comment: All you need is `int *null_test = 0;`

Comment: `int x` defines an `int`. An `int` cannot be `NULL` by definition. Just a pointer can  be `NULL`.

Comment: @Amad27 I would suggest reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11965368/6527069) to help understand just WHY uninitialized variables can give undefined behavior.

Comment: The variable in question actualle _is_ very well initialized. `null_test` has a value assigned. Only `*null_test` is uninitialized

Comment: @LudvigRydahl x is not a pointer. How could it point _anywhere_? It has a specific location, (probably on the stack) which of course can contain garbage. But the value of x is not read anywhere. Neither directly, nor via `null_test`. Is taking the address without reading from it undefined behaviour?

Comment: The address of a valid variable is always a valid pointer, so null_test points to a valid memory address.

Comment: @LudvigRydahl Deleting your last comment makes our responses pointless. Nevertheless the initial comment still makes an incorrect reference to UB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After

```
int *null_test = &x;
```

`null_test` contains the address of `x`. This address is independent of the content of `x` even if `x` has never been initialized.

Answer (score 5):

> Why? I didn't even initializex but still not null?

You need to differentiate between 1) definition and 2) initialisation. A variable is defined when the memory is allocated to it. A variable is initialised when that memory location is filled in with some value.

Here `x` is uninitialised but already *defined* - that means being *allocated* - that means `x` has a specific location in memory. And so `&x` is not NULL and so `null_test`:

`int *null_test = &x;`

If you want `null_test` to be NULL, just assign it explicitly

`int *null_test = NULL;`

Comment: defined to 0 by default?

Comment: No, uninitialised local variable means that it can gets any value - no guarantee of zero.